# AngularJS one click on element and click+hold more 5 seconds

Tags: angularjs, onclick, click

I have the div element and I need catch event of one click and click and hold.

If happened one click of this div, i should call function 1 in scope, if click and hold (more of 5 seconds) i should call function 2 in scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a directive `on-click-and-hold` and use it.

**Directive**

```
directive('onClickAndHold', function ($parse, $timeout) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var clickAndHoldFn = $parse(attrs.onClickAndHold);
      var doNotTriggerClick;
      var timeoutHandler;
      element.on('mousedown', function () {
          $timeout.cancel(timeoutHandler);
          timeoutHandler = $timeout(function () {
            clickAndHoldFn(scope, {$event: event})
          }, 5000)
      });
      element.on('mouseup', function (event) {
          $timeout.cancel(timeoutHandler);
      });

      if (attrs.onClick) {
          var clickFn = $parse(attrs.onClick);
          element.on('click', function (event) {
              if (doNotTriggerClick) {
                  doNotTriggerClick = false;
                  return;
              }
              clickFn(scope, {$event: event});
              scope.$apply();
          });
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**Markup**

```
<div on-click-and-hold="f2()" on-click="f1()"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.f1 = function () {
        console.warn('inside f1');
    }
    $scope.f2 = function () {
        console.warn('inside f2');
    }
})
```

If you want to handle only the click event use `ng-click` instead of `on-click-and-hold`.

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wELOu59GA85Uz8DaO5sE?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you so much! But function $scope.f2 calls after mouseup, and i need call $scope.f2 when i mousehold 5 and more seconds. Could you correct code please? :)

Comment: There's no reason you need jquery for this.  Still good answer

Comment: Is `start`really needed?

Comment: @BrunoPeres, Yeah. start is not required here. Earlier implementation needed that. Forgot to remove it when I updated the implementation to use $timeout.

Comment: to make this work for mobile or touch devices, use `element.on('touchstart'` and `element.on('touchend'` events.